# Iterating through a list of variable to build tmp

Tags: sql, variables, loops, rows

I have a large set of numbers used as a variable in comparing two queries.  The queries are rather time consuming to run so I would like to be able to do this automatically to sort out all variables which have different rows returned by the two queries.  I am open to any suggestions.

The numbers used for @key are on another server.  I have a third query to return these numbers.

I will post the two queries below.

```
  DECLARE @SubscriberID bigint
  DECLARE @key int
  set @key = 128604576

  SELECT TOP(1) @SubscriberID = M.WarehouseID
  FROM vwCache_Full V (NOLOCK)
  LEFT JOIN Latest m (NOLOCK)
  ON m.WarehouseID = v.PersonKey 
  WHERE V.memberid = @key   
  ORDER BY
  V.tapeid DESC, V.linekeyid DESC 


  SELECT TOP 1
        AddrLn1, AddrLn2 
  FROM Latest 
  WHERE 
        WarehouseID = @SubscriberID 
  ORDER BY 
        TapeID DESC, LineKeyID DESC
```

-- NEXT QUERY

```
  SELECT TOP 1 m.AddrLn1, m.AddrLn2
  FROM Latest m (NOLOCK)
  INNER JOIN Latest p ON m.WarehouseID = p.WarehouseID 
  WHERE m.SSN = @key
  ORDER BY m.TapeID Desc
```

Found another answer here that helped with this... using...

```
DECLARE @RowsToProcess  int
DECLARE @CurrentRow     int
DECLARE @SelectCol1     int

DECLARE @table1 TABLE (RowID int not null primary key identity(1,1), col1 int )  
INSERT into @table1 (col1) SELECT col1 FROM table2
SET @RowsToProcess=@@ROWCOUNT

SET @CurrentRow=0
WHILE @CurrentRow<@RowsToProcess
BEGIN
    SET @CurrentRow=@CurrentRow+1
    SELECT 
        @SelectCol1=col1
        FROM @table1
        WHERE RowID=@CurrentRow

    --do your thing here--
```

END